# Choose next view-state dynamically based on Model state?

Tags: java, spring, workflow, spring-webflow

With Spring WebFlow, is it possible to avoid hard-wiring the possible transitions between view-states ?

I am thinking of getting the name of the next `view-state` based on model validation rules.

That would be a way of creating a work-flow based on the model state.

Comment: Could you please add few more points, what do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, that's exactly what WebFlow is for. Either `<action-state>` or `<decision-state>` give you the ability to examine model objects (and other objects) and choose different transitions based on what you read.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this solves my requirement. I had some more insights reading this question&answer:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11994847/spring-webflow-decision-state-vs-action-state